# Boost auto-link gets the wrong version

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I built latest Boost from Git repo (1.56) for VS2013, but somehow it still tries to link to the 1.55 library version of serialization:

`error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib'`

I have the 1.56 .libs in the stage directory, so the build process worked fine.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found `BOOST_LIB_VERSION` and `BOOST_VERSION` in `version.hpp` and changed them to 1.56. I suppose they haven't yet been updated to reflect the library files built.